# How to make the search most efficient?

Tags: performance, search, architecture

For a property sale/rent website, a search function should be provided. At the same time, users can use the filters to get the result they want most.
Normally, there are many attributions of a property, like the price, address, the year built, area, many amenties such as balcony, washing-machine and so on. maybe it's over 100.

So how to design the database(mysql or other nosql) and artitecher to make the search performance to be the most efficient?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your application requires a lot more search queries than update queries, and that the search queries are quite diverse.

In this case, try ElasticSearch: You choose some database where you store and modify your data. Then, you should propagate any update to an ElasticSearch index, where you upload a denormalized view of the data, which is closer to what users will expect to get when searching.

https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-setup-MySQL-to-Elasticsearch-replication

Comment: Yes, we have more search queries.